# How to iterate through a string list in kapacitor tick script

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

How to iterate over a string list  in Kapacitor tick script.?

```
var packages = [ 'package1', 'package2' ]
for package in packages  {
   //Do Something..
}
```

Is there any lambda expression to do this